# Asymptotic lines on $ x^2 y^2 + y^2 z^2 + z^2 x^2 = 1 $

Tags: differential-geometry

How are asymptotic lines defined/computed on this implicit surface?

EDIT1:

In Monge  form  $ z = \frac { 1- z^2 y^2}{x^2+y^2}, $ I find later it can be done because it can at all be cast into such form. But I am intersted in the implicit form.

Presumed that it may be a situation which benefits by using implicit differential relations/ more powerful partial derivatives. When could not proceed toward a result for lack of proper formulation,I asked the question.

Actually I now wish to ask how to find asymptotics on surface:

$$ \sin x \cos y   + \sin y \cos z  +\sin z \cos x = 1 $$

Here I cannot find where to start, tried several (u,v) parametrizations, that did not work.